# How to prevent sql without limit in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hive-configuration

Many users are used to using 'select * from tables' in oracle/mysql

But i should not allow them to query like that in hive

Is there any way to prevent a full_table scan in hive?

Like trigger or somethng else?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent full table scan use these settings.

```
set hive.mapred.mode=strict;  --prevent full scan
SET hive.limit.query.max.table.partition=10; --limit partitions to 10
```

Hive will generate exception if partition predicate is not specified:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10041]: No partition predicate found
```

And exception example in case the number of partitions exceeded:

```
SemanticException Number of partitions scanned (=37) on table
```

Comment: Does `hive.mapred.mode` apply for Tez or Spark execution engine? Also, what if table is not partitioned?

Comment: @cricket_007 It is applicable for Tez as well. Do not know about spark. And if table is not partitioned then partition limitation will not work.